# Background Image Won't Display (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I can't get the background-image to display. I thought adding the min-width might make the image visible in case it was really small, but that didn't work. I've checked the url. It works as a normal image if put straight into the body.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = stylesheet href = Father.css>
<title> Very Important Company </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = backs </div>
<div class = header>
<p>
<img src = http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png id = gecko>
</p>
<div class = navigation>
<ul>
<li> SHOP </li>
<li> ABOUT US </li>
<li> RENTALS </li>
<li> CONTACT </li>
<li> PARTIES </li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
<p>
<div class = main>
<p1> Our Eggs
</p1>
</div>
</body>     
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#backs {
     background: white;
     }

#gecko {
    content:url(http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png);
height: 128px;
width: 128px;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px; 
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
}

li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 50px;
min-width: 100%
}

.navigation {
color: black;
letter-spacing: 2px;
float: right;
vertical-align: top;
width: 800px;
height: 70px;
margin-top: 47px;
min-width:800px;
padding-left: 150px;
position: absolute;
}


.main {
color: black;
font-size: 60px;
position: relative;
top: 150px;
background-image: url (http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg);
min-width: 100%;
height: 900px;
border: 2px solid red;
padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: you should be using quotes around your attributes, ie. `<img src="http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png" id="gecko" />`

Comment: PS. `content:` probably shouldnt be used with an `img` tag

Comment: you have many syntax errors. Please fix those and it will work

Comment: your div are not proper and there is no need of background-img

Comment: check the code below

Answer (score 1):

The format for the path to an image in `background-image` is `url(...)` not `url (...)`

So your line should be

```
background-image: url(http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `bakground-image` property rather than `content`

```
background-image:url(http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your css

```
.main {
color: black;
font-size: 60px;
position: relative;
top: 150px;
background-image: url (http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg);
min-width: 100%;
height: 900px;
border: 2px solid red;
padding-top: 100px;
}
```

you have space between `url` and `(http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg);` in the `background-image:`. Remove the space and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just remove the space before `background-image:url` and then check it (code as below) and close the `div` tag in `<div id=backs> </div>`

```
background-image: url(http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg);
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ag7mmpx5/)

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#backs {
     background: white;
     }

#gecko {
    content:url(http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png);
height: 128px;
width: 128px;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px; 
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
}

li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 50px;
min-width: 100%
}

.navigation {
color: black;
letter-spacing: 2px;
float: right;
vertical-align: top;
width: 800px;
height: 70px;
margin-top: 47px;
min-width:800px;
padding-left: 150px;
position: absolute;
}


.main {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://files.vividscreen.info/soft/fc5e9b0dc8833c69951d28bb856b9ef4/Decorated-Easter-Eggs-2880x1920.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: black;
    font-size: 60px;
    height: 900px;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="backs"></div>
<div class ="header">
<p>
<img src = "http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png id = gecko" alt="">
</p>
<div class ="navigation">
<ul>
<li> SHOP </li>
<li> ABOUT US </li>
<li> RENTALS </li>
<li> CONTACT </li>
<li> PARTIES </li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>

<div class ="main">
<p1> Our Eggs
</p1>

</div>
```